# Exponential-like functions on fields other than $\mathbb R$

Tags: field-theory, exponential-function, group-homomorphism

Let $F$ be any field, and say that $\epsilon:F\to F^\times$ is an *exponential-like function* if it is a group homomorphism from the additive group $(F, +)$ to the multiplicative group $(F, \times)$.  That is, $\epsilon$ should satisfy
$$\epsilon(0_F)=1_F$$
$$\epsilon(a+b)=\epsilon(a)\epsilon(b)$$

Such a function generalizes the properties of exponential functions on $\mathbb R$.  Note that for many fields, no nontrivial $\epsilon$ exists.  For example:

1. If $F=\mathbb Z/(p)$ then we would need to have $1=\epsilon(0)=\epsilon(p\cdot 1)=\epsilon(1)^p$, so $\epsilon(1)$ would need to be an element $b$ satisfying $b^p=1$.  But by Fermat's Little Theorem, every $b\in\mathbb Z/(p)$ satisfies $b^p = b$, and therefore the only possible $\epsilon$ is the trivial homomorphism given by $\epsilon(1)=1$.
2. If $F=\mathbb Q$ then no such $\epsilon$ can exist, because we would need $\epsilon(1/n) = \epsilon(1)^{1/n}\in\mathbb Q$ for all $n$, but the only rational number that has rational roots of all orders is $1$.
3. On the other hand, taking $F = \mathbb C$ we have the familiar complex exponential, $\epsilon(x + iy) = \cos(x) + i \sin(y)$, which has all of the desired properties.

I am interested in the general question of which fields admit such an $\epsilon$.  It seems likely that any algebraically-closed field would work, although I'm not sure how to go about proving it.  What about fields like $\mathbb R(x)$?

Comment: Just for reference purposes: A field equipped with an exponential-like function is usually called an [exponential field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_field). These fields have been extensively studied, especially by model-theorists, but I'm not sure if there's a good characterization of which fields admit non-trivial exponential-like functions. See the wikipedia article for the argument that such a field must have characteristic $0$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman thank you, that's very helpful.

Comment: For $\mathbb{R}(x)$: This field is an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space, so the identity map $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ extends to a group homomorphism $\mathbb{R}(x)\to \mathbb{R}$. Then compose this with the usual exponential map $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and the inclusion $\mathbb{R}\subseteq \mathbb{R}(x)$ to get a non-trivial exponential-like function on $\mathbb{R}(x)$.

Comment: Actually, I guess that argument shows that an exponential-like function on a field $K$ can be extended to any extension field of $K$! So your question really comes down to understanding the minimal extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ which admit such functions.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Maybe it's just late at night and I'm tired, but I don't see how the identity map $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ extends to a group homomorphism $\mathbb R(x) \to \mathbb R$.  Where do we map $x$?  To any arbitrary real number $\alpha$?  Is it then just the evaluation map induced by $x\mapsto\alpha$?  No, that can't be what you mean, because any rational function with $(x-\alpha)$ in the denominator wouldn't map to a real number...

Comment: I just meant to use linear algebra: extend $\{1\}$ to a basis for $\mathbb{R}(x)$ as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space, and send $1$ to $1$ and every other basis element to $0$ (or wherever you like). We don't care about the multiplicative structure, so $\frac{1}{x}$ and $x$ (which are linearly independent!) can both be mapped to $0$.

Comment: Ah, I see.  So basically you map every element $t$ of a Hamel basis to some arbitrarily chosen $s_t$ and then just extend by linearity.  Got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty simple because the structure of the additive group $F$ is very simple: it's just a big direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Q}$ in characteristic $0$, or of $\mathbb{F}_p$ in characteristic $p$.  So, there is a nontrivial homomorphism $F\to F^\times$ iff there is a nontrivial homomorphism $F_0\to F^\times$ where $F_0$ is the prime subfield.

In characteristic $p$, there is no nontrivial such homomorphism, since any element of its image is an element $a\in F$ such that $a^p=1$, and the only such element is $1$ (since $x^p-1$ factors as $(x-1)^p$).

In characteristic zero, there is a nontrivial homomorphism $\mathbb{Q}\to F^\times$ iff $F$ has an element besides $1$ which has an $n$th root for all $n$ (given such an element, you can choose a system of compatible $n!$th roots for each $n$ by König's infinity lemma and then map $1/n!$ to the chosen $n!$th root).  In particular, such an element exists if $F$ is algebraically closed, for instance.

A rather different question is whether there is a *natural* or *useful* exponential function.  The examples above are highly artificial, as they involve picking a basis for $F$ over the prime field (which often cannot be done without the axiom of choice).  I don't know of examples besides subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ which have an exponential function which is good for anything.  The $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_p$ have a natural and useful "exponential function" (defined by the usual power series) but it is not defined on the entire field (only on the proper subset where the power series converges, which turns out to be $p\mathbb{Z}_p$ for $p\neq 2$ and $p^2\mathbb{Z}_p$ for $p=2$) and so it does not meet your definition.

Comment: The $p$-adic case is interesting because the logarithm can easily be extended to a homomorphism on all of $\mathbb{Q}_p^\times$, but the exponential can't be extended to $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (although it can be "extended" as a multi-valued function with values in the algebraic closure if you're willing to pick roots of things). The exact opposite of the case for the complexes!

Comment: For a "natural" solution in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q$ we could try $x \mapsto 2^x$.  But wait.  $2^x$ is algebraic for rational $x$, but $2^x$ is transcendental for irrational algebraic $x$.  That won't work.

Comment: @GEdgar in fact my question was in part motivated by that example, along with the other examples in my question.